# how do I prevent memory error for the following code

Tags: python, python-2.7

This my python code it's working fine for small values as in primary testcases, but producing `Memory Error` due to large integer values. How can remove the Memory Error or how do I perform operations with large integers in python please?

```
#taking input testcases T
n=int(raw_input())

#taking value range upto iterate and find reversible numbers
_input_var = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(0,n)]


#function will reverse the number and return
def reverse(num):
    return int(str(num)[::-1])

#function will check odd confirmation for every digit 
def isDigitOdd(num):
    lista = str(num)
    for i in lista:
        if int(i)%2==0:
            flag = False
            return flag
        else:
            flag = True
    return flag

#main method
def main(_iter):    
    count=0
    for i in range(0,_iter):
        k = i + reverse(i)
        if i%10!=0 and isDigitOdd(k):
            count+=1
    print count

#calling main method for N number ranges
for i in _input_var:
    main(i)
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Exactly which value of `n` gives you an error? Show the entire callback.

Comment: thanks i will try with `xrange` and tell.

Comment: nope! , still getting timeout on other testcases.

Comment: @RISHABMITTAL timeouts have nothing to do with memory issues. Did `xrange` solve the Memory Error issue? If yes, than your question is answered. Improving speed is a different question that is related to your algorithm and optimisations.

Comment: Could you say what means *still getting timeout*. I've already used Python for looong processing (started on friday 17h and ended on monday 10h) without any timeout problem...

Comment: the constraint for the input values are `N<=10^18` and i am getting memory error when i am using values like : `10000000`, I am getting timeouts due to the memory error.

Comment: You won't get `MemoryError` out of `xrange`, it can only throw `OverflowError`, when the number doesn't fit a `long int`, and 10^18 fits quite well on any 64-bit system.

Comment: this question is here: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler145

Comment: @Bhansa I guess, his brute-force algorithm is too naïve.

Comment: @SergeBallesta -- He's getting "timeouts" because this is a Project Euler problem. While a brute force solution might be ultimately correct, it will nonetheless be rejected because it's CPU usage exceeds some limit.

Comment: @RISHABMITTAL - Suppose it takes only a nanosecond for each cycle through the main loop. That means it will take 10^9 seconds (almost 32 years) to finish in the case of 10^18. Note that there is no way the test computer will calculate `n+reverse(n)` in a nanosecond, let alone checking whether each digit in the sum is odd. A brute force solution will take several centuries to arrive at an answer. You cannot use brute force to solve this problem.

Comment: Without an explicit reference to the actual problem, this question was unclear. References were only added in comments and not even by OP :-(

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you run out of memory when a big number is passed to `range`, because it has to build the entire list in memory. Replace `range` calls with `xrange`.

```
def main(_iter):    
    count=0
    for i in xrange(0,_iter):
        k = i + reverse(i)
        if i%10!=0 and isDigitOdd(k):
            count+=1
    print count
```

`xrange` is a lazy generator that, similarly to `range` in Python 3, has O(1) memory complexity. `xrange` uses a 64-bit C `long int` on 64-bit platforms to store internal state, that is the limit is almost ±10^19 (it throws `OverflowError` if a number exceeds that limit). Anyway, as I've already mentioned in the comments (along with other users) your algorithm is too naïve to handle a big input. You must reduce the asymptotic complexity. Something like O(log(n)) should do just fine.

P.S.
Some minor optimisations

```
def isDigitOdd(num):
    return all(int(digit) % 2 for digit in str(num))

def main(_iter):    
    print(sum(i % 10 and isDigitOdd(i+reverse(i)) for i in xrange(0,_iter)))
```

Comment: your code is returning 0 0 value on providing 2 1000 948 as input.

Comment: @Bhansa fixed that

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this line

```
for i in range(0,_iter)
```

This will create a list of length `_iter`, which will be massive for large values.  You actually don't need to store the whole list; you only need to increment a single integer.  Instead, use `xrange`, which produces a [*generator*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that will only create and store one integer at a time:

```
for i in xrange(0,_iter)
```